# Best way of synchronizing objects trough all pages in ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have posts to show in the home page of my app which I retrieve them from the server as JSON objects. I have a post class and I create an instance for each post that I got. I put those instances into an array and loop trough them in the home page. But the problem starts when the user updates or adds a post in a different page.

I want to show the updated version of the post or the new post when the user comes back to home page. So far, I was doing it with event subscriptions but it really started to get complicated when you have so many things to update and update can happen in more than 1 page.

Also, the subscription code needs to run before any event happens, and I need to put the subscription code to the related pages so that I can change the view when the event happens. But what about the case when user did not visit the page where I subscribe to an event but made some changes so that the event published. The callback function of the event doesn't work because I wasn't even able to subscribe to it.

So, is there any better way of synchronizing data in all necessary pages in ionic v3?

Comment: sounds like good case for redux and ngrx, have you think about it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't think this problem as complicated as I need to use redux or ngrx. Because I don't really need those updates anything else then posts. I am more of a looking for simple ionic or angular native solutions if they have one lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for something simple i suggest to just wrote statefull service

```js
@injectable()
export class StateService {
  public stateChange$ = new Subject();
  private state: any = {};

  public setState(state: any) {
     this.state = state;
     this.stateChange.next(state);
  }

}
```

then in component just get state and subscribe to any change of it:

```js
class ComponentX {
  constructor(private state: StateService) {
    this.state = state.state;
    this.state.state.subscribe(newState => {
      this.state = newState;
    }
  } 
}
```

It's not very scalable solution, but is fast and you don't have to download any new lib.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.